# I'm stuck with MDX query

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

i need sales amount of first month of each quarter

```
WITH SET [FIRSTMONTHOFQTR] AS

DESCENDANTS(
        DESCENDANTS(
            [Date].[Calendar].CURRENTMEMBER,
            [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Quarter]
            ),
            [Date].[Calendar].[Month]
        )

SELECT {
    [Measures].[Sales Amount]
} ON COLUMNS,
{   

[FIRSTMONTHOFQTR]

} ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

With above im getting each month but i need only first month. how can i filter that?

Comment: You can just list the months you need in the set - like January, April, July,Octomber. Another solution would be to write a CASE in the set including some mathematics to see if it divides to 4 for example ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach:

```
WITH 
  SET [Qtrs] AS 
    [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Quarter] 
  SET [FIRSTMONTHOFQTR] AS 
    Generate
    (
      [Qtrs] AS s
     ,Head(Descendants(s.CurrentMember,[Date].[Calendar].[Month]))
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[Sales Amount]} ON COLUMNS
 ,[FIRSTMONTHOFQTR] ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

It returns the following:

[image]